# How can I load particular url in same window on searching matching keyword

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe

I have the following code but it redirects url in new window but I can't load it in same window using iframe .please modify it and help me.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        function redirect(name="action") {
           //look for text inside the NEW textbox
           var input = document.getElementById('query').value.toLowerCase();
            switch(input) {
                case 'keyword1':
                   //put this to see if this code runs 
                   //alert("Test");// UNCOMMENT THIS
                    window.location.replace('page1.html');
                    break;
                case 'keyword2':
                    window.location.replace('page2.html');
                    break;
                default://
                    return true;
                    break;
            }
            return false;//don't let the form submit
        }
</script>

<form action="search/search.php" method="get"onsubmit='return redirect();'>
<input type="text" name="query" id="query"  value="SEARCH" columns="2" 
autocomplete="off" delay="1500"  
onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" 
onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" >
<input type="submit" value="" id="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using

```
window.location.replace('page1.html');
```

Can you try

```
window.location.href('page1.html');
```